# I can't change UIImageView's image on PageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I use UIPageViewController, and my each view have a UIImageView inside UIScrollView. 
And I want to change UIImageView's image when orientation changed. I can control the change event and i change the image but it won't change current views image, it change view before current view.
This is the first method that setup and load image to UIImageView.

```
-(void)loadImageToImageView{

UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:self.imageName];

UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[tempImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height)];
tempImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

self.imageView = tempImageView;

[self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1;

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
```

And this method trigger when orientation changed.

```
-(void)changeImage{

UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:self.landscapeImage];
[self.imageView setImage:image];
```

}

Comment: Post the code where you get the `UIImageView` that is in `self.imageView`. If setting the image works but for the wrong `UIImageView` there is probably something wrong with the logic behind getting the current image view.

Comment: These two methods is in the same .m file, so i think it should be the same UIImageView.

Comment: The problem likely is that you are not changing the `UIPageViewController`'s datasource. Which view controller did you set the datasource to, and can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Image name in the below `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` method

```
-(UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {

     PageViewController *childViewController = [[ZoomContainerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ZoomContainerViewController" bundle:nil]; //load the xib file

     childViewController.imageName = requiredImageString;

     return childViewController;

}
```

Then set the image with that image name in your `PageViewController` Class `viewdidload()` method as:

```
 self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageName];
```